# Small multiplicative order modulo infinitely many primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $a>1$ be an integer. [Artin's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots) claims that if $a$ is not a perfect square, then $a$ is a primitive root modulo infinitely many primes $p$ (which moreover form a subset of positive density). Alternatively, I interested in situations where ${\rm{ord}}_p(a)$ is relatively small compared to $p$ for infinitely many (or a positive density subset of) moduli $p$. So here is my question:

**Question.** What growth conditions on a function $f:\Bbb{N}\rightarrow\Bbb{N}$ guarantee that there exist infinitely many primes $p$ for which ${\rm{ord}}_p(a)\leq f(p)$? What if instead of the infinitude, we demand that the subset of such primes is of positive density?

I think it is very hard to answer this question if one aims for $f={\rm{O}}(\log p)$, because if for instance $k:={\rm{ord}}_p(2)\leq\log_2(2p)$, then $p$ must be a Mersenne prime $2^k-1$, and we do not know if there are infinitely many of those. So let us consider functions of growth ${\rm{O}}(p^\epsilon)$ where $\epsilon\in (0,1)$. Even knowing that there is a function $f={\rm{O}}(p^\epsilon)$ for which the answer to the question above is affirmative when $a=2$ would be very helpful to me.

**Question.** Are there $\epsilon\in (0,1)$ and $C>0$ for which the set of primes $p$ with ${\rm{ord}}_p(2)\leq Cp^\epsilon$ is of positive density?

Comment: Don't simple heuristics suggest that the only function that will work for positive density is $f(p)=p /C$? For instance, they suggest that the average of $(p-1)/\operatorname{ord}_p(a)$ should be finite.

Comment: @WillSawin That's interesting. Can you please write the heuristic for $(p-1)/{\rm{ord}}_p(a)$ in an answer?